# Login form in PHP doesnt work using good login

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and im trying to make register and login page. I made database and registration is working good. But login isn't working. I idę correct username and password but its still says i use wrong password

I tried to rearrange my code and look for help at some YouTube video's but nothing seems to work.

```php
$con = new mysqli("localhost","name","password","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to mysql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

    $uname=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql="select * from users where username='".$uname."'AND password='".$password."'limit 1 ";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
        echo "Good password";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo "Wrong password";
        exit();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: **Don't store your passwords in plain-text!** This is not secure *at all!* PHP has built-in functions which you should use to handle storing of passwords, see the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which is a lot more secure!

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).
 Get started with [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) and [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam).

Comment: You're not doing any error-checking. What does `$result` return? what does `mysqli_num_rows($result)` return? Do you even enter `if(isset($_POST['username']))`? [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) will give you clues about any SQL errors.

Comment: You referring to the missing space after the ending quote, @Marvin? Not neccesarily a syntax error, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db1947/1

Comment: I dont want to care about security right now, I just want it to work with plain-text. Thank you for your reply but it doesnt solve a problem at all :(

Comment: Saying that you don't want to care about security now is basically saying that you want to do your work twice - first insecure, then secure. Just learn how to do it the proper way first, easier for you - and you make better programs for it. Making it secure and proper from the get-go isn't difficult, just a different approach - do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark try

`$sql="select * from users where username='$uname' AND password='$password' limit 1";`

It looks like a sql formatting/syntax error honestly. I could be wrong though.

Also I would listen to the comments above, but this looks like more of a learning experience :)

I typed this out on my phone so bear with me I would try this.

```
$uname=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

if(!empty{$uname) && !empty($password))
{
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
        echo "User and Password Provided";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
                echo "Good User and Password";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "Bad User and or Password";
        }
}
else { echo "No user name and or password entered"; )
```

That code is not by any means secure or complete it should work though.

If the above isn't working then I would say you have a form error somewhere.